# Particle system images

Tags: particles

i want to know how i can set the smoke images right on the balls, i use the particles system. I want the particle system to use smoke images. thank you[image]

Answer (score -1):

Create a plane for your image to be on. put the image on it with (with alpha transparency). In particle system settings under "render" chose Render as "Object". select your plane.

Made you this quick video
EDIT:[Image as smoke](https://youtu.be/WyWDAcmUcrA)

shoudl work now

Comment: your link does not work